# Porting legacy api(PropertyGrid's GetFirstCategory/GetNextCategory) to wxPython Phoenix

Tags: wxpython

I am porting an application from wxPython 2.8 to wxPython phoenix(4.0.5a1). and I encountered below problem about PropertyGrid.

AttributeError: 'PropertyGrid' object has no attribute 'GetFirstCategory'

I checked the api docs for wyPython phoenix, and I found these api have already been removed in phoenix project. And I only find "getFirst" in api docs.

`first = self.mpropgrid.GetFirstCategory()
target = self.mpropgrid.GetNextCategory(first)
self.mpropgrid.Delete(target)
self.mpropgrid.Append(wxpg.PropertyCategory("Extra Info"))`

If I want to do the above operations in wxPython phoenix, how should I change my code? I guess I need to convert the code based on iterator operations, but still can't figure out how to implement, any suggestion would be appropriated, thank you!

Comment: The `GetFirst(self, flags=PG_ITERATE_ALL)` flags could be set to `wx.propgrid.PG_PROP_CATEGORY` have you tried that? See https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.propgrid.PGPropertyFlags.enumeration.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I tired it and found it works.